# Cannot access/delete the Secret Gists from Github Account even with correct Auth details

Tags: node.js, github, node-modules, async.js, octokit

I have searched a very lot for this but couldn't found anything useful, and I am not a fluent Nodejs developer.

I am trying to delete my old and outdated secret gists from my Github Account with the below code, but it only does the Authentication part correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const Octokit = require('@octokit/rest')
const octokit = new Octokit()

var async = require('async');
var github = new Octokit({
    version: '14.0.0',
    protocol: 'https'
});

github.authenticate({
    type: 'basic',
    username: '###############',
    password: '###############'
});

async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        console.log(github.gists.getAll());
        github.gists.getAll({}, callback);
    },
    function (gists, callback) {
        // filter gists by properties as needed
        async.each(gists, function (gist, callback) {
            github.gists.delete({
                id: gist.id
            }, callback);
        }, callback);
    }
], function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Execution failed: %s', err.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('Done!');
    process.exit(0);
});
```

When I run the above script in Gitbash(Windows 7 64Bit with Node and Npm installed), it gives this error:

```
Promise { <pending> }
Execution failed: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

But I know those secret gists are there.

It doesn't even list out those secret gists when I do like,

```
console.log(gist.id)
```

right after `async` function call.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an outdated `@octokit/rest`. Make sure you have the last version installed, v16.3.1 at this time. You can check which version you have installed by running `npm ls @octokit/rest` in your terminal.

Because you are potentially loading and deleting a lot of gists, I would recommend to use the [throttle plugin](https://github.com/octokit/plugin-throttling.js). It will help you prevent hitting abuse/rate limits. Here is the full code.

```js
const Octokit = require('.')
  .plugin(require('@octokit/plugin-throttling'))

const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: {
    username: '###############',
    password: '###############'
  },
  throttle: {
    onAbuseLimit: (retryAfter) => console.log(`abuse limit hit, retrying after ${retryAfter}s`),
    onRateLimit: (retryAfter) => console.log(`rate limit hit, retrying after ${retryAfter}s`)
  }
})

// load all your gists, 100 at a time.
octokit.paginate('/gists?per_page=100')
  .then((gists) => {
    // filter out the public gists
    const privateGists = gists.filter(gist => !gist.public)
    console.log(`${privateGists.length} gists found`)

    // delete all private gists
    return Promise.all(privateGists.map(gist => octokit.gists.delete({ gist_id: gist.id }))
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('done')
  })
```

Instead of authenticating with your username and password, I would recommend to create a private access token. Make sure to select the "gist" scope: https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=gist&description=deleting%20private%20gists

Then pass the token to the constructor’s auth option instead of username and password

```js
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: 'token <your token here>',
  throttle: {
    onAbuseLimit: (retryAfter) => console.log(`abuse limit hit, retrying after ${retryAfter}s`),
    onRateLimit: (retryAfter) => console.log(`rate limit hit, retrying after ${retryAfter}s`)
  }
})
```